# Correct syntax for including .* directories with tar

Tags: tar

I'm trying to include files that match `*/*/.thisdirectory/*` in a tar archive. What's the correct syntax? Apparently this is not:

```
> find .
.
./bar
./bar/.a
./bar/.a/baz
./foo
./foo/.a
> tar --include "*[.]a*" -cvf a.tar .
>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your shell is bash, you can use the `GLOBIGNORE` variable to hide the `.` and `..` directories. This does automatically also set the `dotglob` option, so `*` now matches both hidden and non-hidden files:

```
GLOBIGNORE=".:.."
tar czf tarball-with-hidden-files.tgz directory/*
```

To expand on this a bit: by default, `*` does not match hidden files (files starting with a `.`), which includes the current (`.`) and parent (`..`) directories of any directory.  If you want a glob (e. g. a command line wildcard) to match them, you need to set the `dotglob` option, but this can cause *really* bad things to happen if `..` matches `*` and you do something like `rm -fr /home/olduser/*` (because `olduser/..` matches, which is `/home/` and now you've just fried everyones' home directories.  Which is where `GLOBIGNORE` comes into play- it blacklists things from matching wildcards.  As a really simple use-case:

```
ghoti@home:~/scratch$ ls -ld ?dotfile
ls: cannot access '?dotfile': No such file or directory
ghoti@home:~/scratch$ touch _dotfile .dotfile
ghoti@home:~/scratch$ ls -ld ?dotfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ghoti ghoti 0 May  6 16:58 _dotfile
ghoti@home:~/scratch$ GLOBIGNORE=".:.."
ghoti@home:~/scratch$ ls -ld ?dotfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ghoti ghoti 0 May  6 16:58 _dotfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ghoti ghoti 0 May  6 16:58 .dotfile
```

What does this mean for you?  Well, as in the quick example at the top of this answer, once you set `GLOBIGNORE` to ignore `.` and `..`, you can use `*` to match hidden directories like the ones you're trying to archive:

```
tar czf mytarball.tgz directory/*  # this will include things like directory/.hiddenfile
```

To point this at your specific example of a directory called `.a`:

```
ghoti@home:~/scratch$ mkdir -p example example/foo/.a example/bar/.a example/foo/_a example/bar/_a
ghoti@home:~/scratch$ touch example/{foo,bar}/{.,_}a/file
ghoti@home:~/scratch$ find example/
example/
example/foo
example/foo/_a
example/foo/_a/file
example/foo/.a
example/foo/.a/file
example/bar
example/bar/_a
example/bar/_a/file
example/bar/.a
example/bar/.a/file
ghoti@home:~/scratch$ GLOBIGNORE=".:.."
ghoti@home:~/scratch$ tar cvzf withdotfiles.tgz example/*/?a
example/bar/_a/
example/bar/_a/file
example/bar/.a/
example/bar/.a/file
example/foo/_a/
example/foo/_a/file
example/foo/.a/
example/foo/.a/file
ghoti@home:~/scratch$ unset GLOBIGNORE
ghoti@home:~/scratch$ tar cvzf withoutdotfiles.tgz example/*/?a
example/bar/_a/
example/bar/_a/file
example/foo/_a/
example/foo/_a/file
```

Comment: I must be missing something, because that doesn't improve the situation at all:

`> GLOBIGNORE=".:.." tar --include "*[.]a*" -cvf a.tar .
>` The .* directories get included just fine without `--include` but trying to restrict what gets tarred fails utterly...

Comment: @cbmanica the command you show in no way resembles DopeGhoti's example nor does it `*/*/.thisdirectory/*` so clarifications are needed on what files you want to include.

Comment: I thought it was extremely clear that I want to include files that match ".foo" from a current directory. If my command didn't match that, maybe that's because I at no time indicated I was dealing with a tgz.

Comment: I suppose given that `find . | grep "[.]thisdirectory" > files; tar -cf my.tar -T files` does what I want, this is all academic, but I get tired of SO being so willfully pedantic in response to all questions.

Comment: Without specific questions, it's exceedingly difficult to give specific answers.

Comment: It's very specific. I want subdirectories named ".a" included in tar. Simple. What's not clear about that?

Comment: Or even more explicitly, doing exactly what you said, `shopt -s dotglob; GLOBIGNORE=".:.." tar --include "*[.]a*" -cvf a.tar .` does not include the files in the `.a` subdirectories in the tar archive. If you post something that does that, I'll gladly accept. I don't know how much more clearly I can state what I want.

Comment: Happy to. See the latest amendment to my answer.

Comment: @cbmanica `GLOBIGNORE` is a bash feature, it has no effect on tar. That's why DopeGhoti is passing patterns on the command line of tar, rather than giving it `--include` options.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using FreeBSD tar¹ as this is the only implementation I know with a `--include` option.

When you pass `--include`, only explicitly included files are traversed. When building an archive, if a directory isn't traversed then neither it nor any of its contents can be included. Since you're tarring `.` but not including `.`, the sole command line argument doesn't get included, and you get an empty archive.

To reach the `.a` directories, you would need to include all the parent directories. The thing is, if you do that, then all of their contents will be included as well. You can use `--exclude` to exclude them, but then you need an exclude pattern that doesn't exclude the dot directories that you want to include. At this point `--include` is no longer of any use. The `--include` option is rarely useful when creating an archive, it's rather more useful when copying part of an existing archive (because when doing that, there's no recursive traversal, just iteration through the list of members of the input archive).

```
tar --exclude='./*/[!.]*' -cvf a.tar .
```

Note that all files in the toplevel directory are included. I don't think there's a way to include only those directories that will have non-empty contents.

To get only the `./*/.*` directories and nothing else (in particular not their parent directories), you need to pass them as arguments to tar, rather than let tar recurse to find them.

```
tar -cvf a.tar ./*/.[!.]*/
```

Remove the trailing slash to include files that aren't directories (or symlinks to directories). Add `./*/..?*/` to include directories whose name begins with `..` if you have those.

¹  <sub>Possibly under a different operating system.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Rather jumping on an old horse here, but, since I can't find any evidence of anyone pointing out the apparently "intended" way that this should be done with tar:

The issue, as has been noted elsewhere, is that tar is quite literal with "--include", and it won't traverse into directories foo and bar to find your .a files, if the --include filters them off first.

The clue to the trick to using tar as you'd like to use it /is/ included in the man page, but it's fairly well obfuscated:  --include is "supposed" to be used to filter existing archives; Also, there is a magic argument @- that causes tar to treat a read from STDIN as a read from an existing archive.

Put together, you can use one promiscuous tar statement to create an archive of everything below the current directory, and stuff it onto STDOUT.  You then pipe this into a tar that's going to use the --include option, *and* that reads from STDIN.

In your case, this looks something like:

tar -cf - */ | tar -cf myfiles.tar --include="*.a" @-

```
Soyokaze:test$ ls -lR
total 32
drwxr-xr-x   6 tyler  staff   204 Nov 29 14:24 bar/
drwxr-xr-x   4 tyler  staff   136 Nov 29 14:23 foo/

./bar:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 tyler  staff    0 Nov 29 14:23 baa.a
-rw-r--r--  1 tyler  staff    0 Nov 29 14:23 baaa.a
-rw-r--r--  1 tyler  staff    0 Nov 29 14:23 baz
drwxr-xr-x  2 tyler  staff   68 Nov 29 14:24 boos/

./bar/boos:
total 0

./foo:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 tyler  staff    0 Nov 29 14:23 baa.a
-rw-r--r--  1 tyler  staff    0 Nov 29 14:23 baz.a

Soyokaze:test$ tar -cf - */ | tar -cf myfiles.tar --include="*.a" @-

Soyokaze:test$ tar -tf myfiles.tar
bar/baa.a
bar/baaa.a
foo/baa.a
foo/baz.a
```